# is there anything that i don't know about Json in Code

Tags: android, json

i'm trying to do some work with methods of json in android.
i read the documentation of json and its methods but when i use them,they don't do what i expected they do.

```
public class getData_jason extends AsyncTask{

    String KholaseKQuery;
    String User;

public getData_jason(String link,String user) {
    KholaseKQuery = link;
    User = user;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object[] params) {

    try{

        URL mylink = new URL(KholaseKQuery);

        URLConnection connect = mylink.openConnection();

        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();
        String eline;
        while((eline = read.readLine())!= null)
        {
            sB.append(eline);
        }
        //MainActivity.jason_rs = sB.toString();
        MainActivity.result = sB.toString();
        MainActivity.is = true;
        JSONObject jObj;
        try{

            jObj = new JSONObject(MainActivity.result.replace("callback(","")).getJSONObject("response");
            JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.optJSONArray("Username");

            for (int i = 0;i < jsonArray.length();i++){

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                if (jsonObject.getBoolean("ali")){
                    MainActivity.jason_rs = jsonObject.optString("Name");
                    //MainActivity.jason_rs = jsonObject.getString("Name");
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        /*Any Exception Here*/
    }
    return "";
}
```

}

when the process of reading from database is finished,in the result string is:

```
{"Username":["Name":"ali","Name":"hasan"]},{"Password":["aliali","hasanhasan"]}
```

so when i want to get ali name from the jsonObject,the value of jason_rs is null.
plz guid me what is that i don't know yet about using json or i do it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "json" is invalid. You can't have the same key more than once in a hash, on the other hand you also can't have keys (certainly not strings) in an array. You can validate it on http://jsonlint.com